# Parallelizing in-memory tasks in dask using shared memory (no sending to other processes)?

Tags: dask

I have a trivially parallelizable in-memory problem, but one that which does not give great speedups with regular Python multiprocessing (only 2xish), due to the need for sending lots of data back and forth between processes. Hoping dask can help.

My code basically looks like this:

```
delayed_results = []
for key, kdf in natsorted(scdf.groupby(grpby_key)):
    d1 = dd.from_pandas(kdf, npartitions=1)
    d2 = dd.from_pandas(other_dfs[key], npartitions=1)

    result = dask.delayed(function)(d1, d2, key=key, n_jobs=n_jobs, **kwargs)
    delayed_results.append(result)

outdfs = dask.compute(*delayed_results)
```

This is what my old joblib code looked like:

```
outdfs = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs)(delayed(function)(scdf, other_dfs[key], key=key, n_jobs=n_jobs, **kwargs) for key, scdf in natsorted(scdf.groupby(grpby_key)))
```

However, the dask code is much much slower and more memory-consuming, both for the threaded and multiprocessing schedulers. I was hoping that dask could be used to parallelize tasks without needing to send stuff to other processes. Is there a way to use multiple processes with dask by using shared memory?

---

Btw. The docs have a reference to http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/local-cluster.html where they explain that this scheduler

> It handles data locality with more sophistication, and so can be more
>   efficient than the multiprocessing scheduler on workloads that require
>   multiple processes.

But they have no examples of its usage. What should I replace my `dask.compute()` call with in the code above to try the local cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can just do the following

```
from distributed import LocalCluster, Client
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=4)
client = Client(cluster)

<your code>
```

Distributed will by default register itself as the executor, and you can just use dask.compute as normal